# autofinancer vs s'autofinancer

Tags: grammaire, usage, verbes, préfixes, pronoms-réfléchis

Est-ce que l'emploi du pronom *se* devant autofinancer ou d'autres verbes préfixés d'*auto* est grammaticalement correct ?

Il me semble que le préfixe auto renvoi déjà au sujet ce qui rend l'emploi de *se* redondant. Mais j'ai quand même un doute. Sur CNRTL, la forme pronominale n'existe pas tandis que sur [Larousse](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/autofinancer/6701?q=s%20autofinancer#6671), la forme existe mais la différence entre les deux formes (sans et avec *se*) n'est pas expliquée.

Y a-t-il une différence de sens entre les deux formes ? Par exemple, si l'on se réfère au titre d'[un article](http://www.lemonde.fr/economie/article/2015/10/14/l-enseignement-superieur-peut-il-s-autofinancer_4789269_3234.html) dans Le Monde "L'enseignement supérieur peut il s'autofinancer ?" Quelle serait la différence entre :

1. L'enseignement supérieur peut-il s'autofinancer ?
2. L'enseignement supérieur peut-il autofinancer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

D'un point de vue grammatical, il y a trois possibilités :

- Le verbe n'appelle pas de complément : il indique une caractéristique du sujet qui se finance par lui-même. Dans ce cas il n'y a pas de pronom *se*.
- Le verbe appelle un complément d'objet direct qui indique ce qui est financé. Dans ce cas, le COD peut être le pronom *se*, indiquant que ce qui est financé est le sujet.
- Le verbe est pronominal et ne peut se construire qu'avec un pronom réfléchi. Dans ce cas, *se* fait partie intégrante du verbe.

La grammaire ne peut pas trancher entre ces possibilités. Seul l'usage le peut.

Dans le cas d'*autofinancer*, l'exemple donné par le [TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/autofinancer) (« l'Office est invité à autofinancer largement les investissements ») montre que le verbe appelle un COD. Le sujet est l'entité dont le budget est concerné, et le complément est la ligne budgétaire concernée. Ce n'est pas un verbe réfléchi puisqu'il y a un complément direct distinct du sujet.

La construction réfléchie est [la plus fréquente](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=autofinancer_INF%2Cs%27autofinancer_INF&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t3%3B%2Cautofinancer_INF%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bautofinance%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bautofinancent%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bautofinan%C3%A7ait%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cs%27autofinancer%3B%2Cc0), mais ce n'est pas le sens « primitif », c'est une métonymie dans laquelle le complément est l'entité elle-même pour désigner l'ensemble de ses dépenses. Le complément n'est pas redondant puisqu'il précise que c'est l'ensemble des dépenses (par opposition à une dépense en particulier) qui est financée sans aide extérieure.

Comment: Le ngram ne fonctionne pas pour moi, je ne sais pas si c'est ce que tu voulais dire.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez C'est un bug de Ngram, si tu cliques sur le bouton “Search lots of books” le graphe s'affiche, et pourtant c'est la même URL.

Comment: Yes but `s'autofinancer_INF` doesn't seem to be recognized properly by the engine. Or wait, could it be true that *autofinancer* was always inflected and *s'autofinancer* never was in this corpus?

Answer (score 5):

Tout d'abord je pense que tu peux aller regarder sur cette page https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/autofinancer qui donne des exemples pour "autofinancer" et "s'autofinancer". La différence se remarque facilement.

"L'enseignement supérieur peut-il autofinancer?" est une forme incorrecte. Qu'est-ce que l'enseignement supérieur peut autofinancer? Un projet? Une fête? Dans ce cas tu as obligatoirement besoin d'un complément selon moi.

"L'enseignement supérieur peut-il s'autofinancer?" là, on comprend que c'est de son activité en général. Autofinancer toute son "entreprise".

Je ne suis pas capable d'expliquer cela correctement et cette réponse est 'instinctive'. J'espère qu'elle pourra apporter une aide, ou une piste le temps qu'une meilleure réponse soit donnée.